# Find "offending" script/file cause multiple connections and hogging resources

Tags: linux, netstat

I am using a Linux VPS running Cyberpanel/CentOS and PHP 7.4.

Using htop and netstat, I can see that there are tons of TCP connections open when my VPS server/website stops responding.  I have numerous scripts that run often throughout the day.
However, I do not know how to tell which specific script is the one causing the bottleneck and bringing the server to a standstill.

Please keep it in a novice language.  I am not very knowledgeable with shell scripts.

Comment: you can use top command to see which process is using most resources `top -o %MEM` will show processes sorted by memory use, `top -o %CPU` will show processes sorted by cpu use, you can also install atop which can be run as a service and take snapshots similar to top that you can then look through and see which processes take most resources at certain times.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the cpu and memory are low and aren’t the problem. Both are only around 20% of capacity. The problem is that some sort of max connections is being hit and I can’t find which setting and I can’t tell which script is causing it.  Other websites on the server work fine. So it is definitely a local se

Comment: if you are looking what is running on a certain port you can use `lsof`, `lsof -i :PORT` will give you all processes having open connection to a certain port. For port 443`lsof -ni tcp:443 | awk '{print$1,$2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n` should show the process and pid that has the highest amount of connections on that port